# How to switch states in phaser frame work?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to switch to the Main Menu state in phaser through a function but couldn't get it to work. Below is my code snippet. The end function is called from the update function in game.js file.

```
end: function(){
    player.kill();
    ltext.setText("Over!!");
    this.state.start('Menu');
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better not to call this function from the update function.

Instead, you can call it from a sprite or button event handler etc.

I tested game.state.start('xx') in update function and it worked as expected.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
 var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 190, Phaser.CANVAS, '', {
  create : function (game) {
      var textStyle = { font: "14px Arial", fill: "#ffcc00" };
      game.add.text(60, 40, 'Phaser HTML5 Game Engine', textStyle);
      game.add.text(60, 70, 'This is state 1', textStyle);
          
      var textStyle = { font: "14px Arial", fill: "#00ff00"};
      game.add.text(200, 130, 'Pointer here to enter state2', textStyle);
      var graphics = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
      graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
      graphics.drawRect(200, 80, 50, 50);
      graphics.endFill();
     },
  update : function (game) {
      var x = game.input.x, y = game.input.y;
      if(x > 200 && x < 250 && y > 80 && y < 130){
       game.state.start('state2');
      }
     }
 });

 game.state.add('state2', {
  create: function (game){
   var textStyle = { font: "14px Arial", fill: "#00ff00"};
      game.add.text(60, 40, 'Phaser HTML5 Game Engine', textStyle);
      game.add.text(60, 70, 'Welcome to state 2', textStyle);
  }
 });
}, false);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;margin:4px;padding:0;}
canvas{vertical-align:middle; background-color:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.3.0/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: in my update function i declared function to constantly check if the player had scored a certain score to reach next level but if i can't use state manager in update function then how can i possibly go to next level?

Comment: I tested state.start in update function and it worked as expected.

Maybe your code have other issues. for example, the **this** is or not the game instance.

Could you paste more code?

Comment: i created my other state in a separate javascript file unlike in same js file

Comment: It doesn't matter where your js files are.